# LPTHW 41 - url failure

Tags: python-2.7

The script includes:

```
import random  
from urllib import urlopen  
import sys  

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"  
WORDS = []  

...  

# load up the words from the website  
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():  
    WORDS.append(word.strip())  

...
```

My problem occurs when I try to run the script. I get the following tracebacks:
[xterm_003.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUsoN.jpg)

Comment: The error you mentioned is in some part of the code that you striped. Show all the code!

Comment: The entire script is 85 lines long and the striped part handles the text once it has been acquired from the website. I confined the above code to the relevant sections that call the url. If you think there is some relevance in the remainder, I could enter it.

Comment: I ran exactly same code from the question and works on Python 2.7

Comment: I'm not sure if the jpeg I attached was visible, so I'll type out the tracebacks I received:

Comment: But your code doesn't uses OrderedDict in no time! Even in the LPTHW example on the site, does not use.

Comment: I don't know if you can see the attached jpeg of the tracebacks, but If your attempt was successful, then I obviously have a problem with my library modules. I have no idea how to get around that. After your comment I wrote the script from scratch, with the exact same tracebacks!